# How to get this Java -program CPLEX working in Ubuntu 11?

Tags: 11.10, java

I am trying to istall the IBM CPLEX [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13373775/164148) and [here](https://www14.software.ibm.com/webapp/iwm/web/reg/signup.do?source=scholars) requiring some Java thing but getting err:

```
/tmp/install.dir.7091/Linux/resource/jre/bin/java: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

I tested it also as sudo and got the same error.

How can I solve this problem?

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the installer looks for `/lib/libc.so.6` and can't find it, and that can be the cause of the error.

In Ubuntu 12.10 that library is stored in `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` (32bit) and `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` (64bit). So you can try to create a symbolic link to one of those files so the installer finds it:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
```

If that don't works then you should use `locate` to find where those library files are stored in 11.10.